Schema.Location standard object does not populate correct root location
Whenever I do mass insert of locations with parent location id.
Then the root location is not correct.
Root location is standard field and cancluated automatically.
The final state is like this -

If you check the Root location, it should be "Root" for all however it is quite random .
I mass insert it using two DML . First I get all data from CSV insert the base level records.
Then in second pass I get all parent location and update the child records with parent reference.
